# multiple split in string using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, split

I have a string :

```
 Station Disconnect:1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.15.2.75.3.2.0.8 StaMAC:00:9F:0B:00:38:B8 BSSID:00 9F Radioid:2
```

I want split this string. It look like this -

```
'Station Disconnect:1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.15.2.75.3.2.0.8' 'StaMAC:00:9F:0B:00:38:B8' 'BSSID:00 9F' 'Radioid:2'
```

I tried this logic - msgRegex = re.compile('[\w\s]+:') and split function also.
How can I do Please help me Thank you

Comment: Simple split with space. `str.split(' ')`

Comment: It does not give proper output @VivekKumar

Comment: I used split function and regex also  msgRegex = re.compile('[\w\s]+:') @RedBassett

Comment: You can use the "edit" button below your original question to add this to the question!

Comment: You can use `split`, And manually joints these area's `Station Disconnect:`,`BSSID:00 9F`.

Comment: @Prafulla: Are you sure you need to *split*? Try [`re.findall(r'(?<!\S)\b([^:]+):((?:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}(?:[ :][a-fA-F0-9]{2})*|\S)+)\b', s)`](https://regex101.com/r/arV7DW/1).

Comment: Thank you very much dear @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, you have a problem when you have a whitespace inside the matches with hex values.

Because of that, I believe you cannot use a splitting approach here. Match your tokens with a regex like

```
(?<!\S)\b([^:]+):((?:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}(?:[ :][a-fA-F0-9]{2})*|\S)+)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/arV7DW/2)

[Python code](https://ideone.com/gRh4aZ):

```
import re

rx = r"(?<!\S)\b([^:]+):((?:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}(?:[ :][a-fA-F0-9]{2})*|\S)+)\b"
ss = ["Station Disconnect:1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.15.2.75.3.2.0.8 StaMAC:00:9F:0B:00:38:B8 BSSID:00 9F Radioid:2",
    "Station Deassoc:1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.15.2.75.3.2.0.5 StaMac1:40:83:DE:34:04:75 StaMac2:40:83:DE:34:04:75 UserName:4083de340475 StaMac3:40:83:DE:34:04:75 VLANId:1 Radioid:2 SSIDName:Devices SessionDuration:12 APID:CN58G6749V AP Name:1023-noida-racking-zopnow BSSID:BC:EA:FA:DC:A6:F1"]
for s in ss:
    matches = re.findall(rx, s)
    print(matches)
```

Result:

```
[('Station Disconnect', '1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.15.2.75.3.2.0.8'), ('StaMAC', '00:9F:0B:00:38:B8'), ('BSSID', '00 9F'), ('Radioid', '2')]
[('Station Deassoc', '1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.15.2.75.3.2.0.5'), ('StaMac1', '40:83:DE:34:04:75'), ('StaMac2', '40:83:DE:34:04:75'), ('UserName', '4083de340475'), ('StaMac3', '40:83:DE:34:04:75'), ('VLANId', '1'), ('Radioid', '2'), ('SSIDName', 'Devices'), ('SessionDuration', '12'), ('APID', 'CN58G6749V'), ('AP Name', '1023-noida-racking-zopnow'), ('BSSID', 'BC:EA:FA:DC:A6:F1')]
```

**NOTE**: If you need no tuples in the result, remove the capturing parentheses from the pattern.

**Pattern details**:

- `(?<!\S)\b` - start of string or whitespace followed with a word boundary (next char must be a letter/digit or `_`)
- `([^:]+)` - Capturing group #1: 1+ chars other than `:`
- `:` - a colon
- `((?:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}(?:[ :][a-fA-F0-9]{2})*|\S)+)` - Capturing group 2 matching one or more occurrences of:

  - `[a-fA-F0-9]{2}(?:[ :][a-fA-F0-9]{2})*` - 2 hex chars followed with zero or more occurrences of a space or `:`  and 2 hex chars
  - `|` - or
  - `\S` - a non-whitespace char
- `\b` - trailing word boundary.

Comment: 'Desc:Unknown Failure APID:CN58G6749V BSSID:BC:EA:FA:DC:A6:F0 AuthMode: 1 AP MAC:BC:EA:FA:DC:A6:E0' For this type of line it doesn't work

Comment: output shoulde be : ['Desc:Unknown Failure' 'APID:CN58G6749V' 'BSSID:BC:EA:FA:DC:A6:F0' 'AuthMode: 1' 'AP MAC:BC:EA:FA:DC:A6:E0']

Comment: Just a sec: how do you delimit the key from the value? That example ruins the whole logic, and keys cannot be distinguished from the values with regex since both keys and values can have arbitrary number of whitespace inside them.

Comment: Ok, a regex is still possible, but only if all the keys are known. If you can provide their list, I can adjust the pattern.

Comment: Keys are not fixed.Keys may change or may be the sequence is changed.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case you can implement it like so:

```
import re

a = 'Station Disconnect:1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.15.2.75.3.2.0.8 StaMAC:00:9F:0B:00:38:B8 BSSID:00 9F Radioid:2'
print re.split(r'(?<=[A-Z0-9]) (?=[A-Z])', a)
```

Output:

```
['Station Disconnect:1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.15.2.75.3.2.0.8', 'StaMAC:00:9F:0B:00:38:B8', 'BSSID:00 9F', 'Radioid:2']
```

Regex:

`(?<=[A-Z0-9])` - Positive lookbehind for A-Z or 0-9

- 1 space character

`(?=[A-Z])` - Positive look ahead for A-Z

Comment: Still it gives something wrong output. line = ' Station Deassoc:1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.15.2.75.3.2.0.5 StaMac1:40:83:DE:34:04:75 StaMac2:40:83:DE:34:04:75 UserName:4083de340475 StaMac3:40:83:DE:34:04:75 VLANId:1 Radioid:2 SSIDName:Devices SessionDuration:12 APID:CN58G6749V AP Name:1023-noida-racking-zopnow BSSID:BC:EA:FA:DC:A6:F1'

Comment: Give me some time, i'll have a look.

Comment: Have you checked this problem? Thank you @MYGz