# Regex (C#): match > < & (illegal XML chars) but only when contained within qutoes

Tags: c#, regex, quotes

I need to do a replacement on the escaped XML chars `>` `<` and `&`, but only when they are contained within single quotes. This is important because the regex pattern shouldn't be able to find the `>` and`<` when they are the beginning and ending tags.

Example, given the string `<Element><Element value="'hello&stack<overflow>'"/></Element>`

I should only get the `>` `<` and `&` that are within the single quotes `'`.
This is so I can replace them with the proper `&amp;` `&lt;` and `&gt;` (Long story it's the result of a muddled XML parsing that happened).

I know I can use `'(.*)'` to get all characters in between the single quotes, but now how can I extract only the escaped characters within that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match a tag name with all consequent attribute names/values and only replace `<` and `>` inside the values (or names as well, depends on how messy your data is).

This can be done within `Regex.Replace` match evaluator:

```
var s = "<Element><Element value=\"'hello&stack<overflow>'\" value=\"'hi&stack<over flow2 >'\"/></Element>";
var rx = @"((?:<[a-zA-Z][\w:-]*|\G(?!\A))\s+[^\s=<]*=)(""[^""]*"")";
var clean = Regex.Replace(s, rx, m => 
    string.Format("{0}{1}", m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value.Replace("&", "&amp;").Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;"))
);
 // => <Element><Element value="'hello&amp;stack&lt;overflow&gt;'" value="'hi&amp;stack&lt;over flow2 &gt;'"/></Element>
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/eUPzXb)

Here is the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%28%3F%3A%3C%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%5B%5Cw%3A-%5D*%7C%5CG%28%3F!%5CA%29%29%5Cs%2B%5B%5E%5Cs%3D%3C%5D*%3D%29%28%22%5B%5E%22%5D*%22%29&i=%3CElement%3E%3CElement%20value%3D%22%27hello%26stack%3Coverflow%3E%27%22%20value%3D%22%27hi%26stack%3Cover%20flow2%20%3E%27%22%2F%3E%3C%2FElement%3E). Details:

- `((?:<[a-zA-Z][\w:-]*|\G(?!\A))\s+[^\s=<]*=)` - Group 1:

  - `(?:<[a-zA-Z][\w:-]*|\G(?!\A))` - either `<`, an ASCII letter, 0+ word chars, `:`, or `-` (see `<[a-zA-Z][\w:-]*`), OR (`|`) the end of the previous successful match (see `\G(?!\A)`)
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `[^\s=<]*=` - 0+ chars other than whitespace, `=` and `<`
- `("[^"]*")` - Group 2:

  - `"[^"]*"` - a `"`, 0+ chars other than `"` and then a `"`

Comment: Check this one also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42065310/multiple-split-in-string-using-regex

Comment: Amazing. That is something I never would have been able to figure out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It works for this case. If you can include more inputs, we can improve and cover them as well.

Check this:

```
(?<!^)(>|<|&)(?=.*')
```

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/EgXlcD/2

Comment: Oops, I spoke too soon, I edited the example with a case where it doesn't work.

Comment: @MH175 Doing it with regex can be a bit difficult. It can be very easily done with an xml parser. I have no exposure to C# or would have done it for you. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c

Comment: Unfortunately that's the problem. The parser (XDocument) won't even run until I correct these errors, and throws an exception because it's encountering all these illegal chars. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Edit: Can be difficult with regex unless you are [Wiktor Stribiżew](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew)